# Is $(\mathbb{Z}_p\times \mathbb{R})/\mathbb{Z}$ connected?

Tags: gn.general-topology, algebraic-number-theory, topological-groups, class-field-theory

I was reading this question [The connected component of the idele class group](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/350676/the-kernel-of-the-global-class-field-theory-homomorphism) but I am very confused about the structure of the *solenoids* $(\widehat{\mathbb{Z}}\times\mathbb{R})/\mathbb{Z}$, (where $\mathbb{Z}$ acts diagonally), more specifically why it is connected. More generally, if we replace $\widehat{\mathbb{Z}}$ by $\mathbb{Z}_p$, is the resulting quotient group $(\mathbb{Z}_p\times \mathbb{R})/\mathbb{Z}$ still connected?

Hoping if someone can give me any hints or answers!!

Comment: Yes. Otherwise, being a compact group, it has a nontrivial finite Hausdorff quotient. So the Pontryagin dual has a nontrivial finite subgroup, i.e., is not torsion-free. But the Pontryagin dual $\mathbf{Z}[1/p]$ is indeed torsion-free.

Comment: @YCor You mean the p-adic solenoid is exactly the Pontryagin dual of $\mathbb{Z}[1/p]$? Then what’s the Pontryagin dual of $(\widehat{\mathbb{Z}}\times\mathbb{R})/\mathbb{Z}$-it can’t be Q obviously

Comment: @YCor Wait,,, is it?

Comment: Yes, it's isomorphic to $\mathbf{Q}$.

Comment: @YCor Then we are done! As $\mathbb{Q}$ is torsion free. This should be the most direct way to see what the solenoid is- the Pontryagin dual of $\mathbb{Q}$. I just don’t know this until today

Comment: @YuanYang The following three exercises may be helpful for you to work out: (a) show that the solenoid group $(\hat {\mathbb Z} \times {\mathbb R})/{\mathbb Z}$ is the inverse limit (in the category of compact abelian groups) of the large circles ${\mathbb R}/N{\mathbb Z}$ (with the directed set structure given by divisibility).  (b) show that the rationals ${\mathbb Q}$ are the direct limit (in the category of discrete abelian groups) of the infinite cyclic groups $\frac{1}{N} {\mathbb Z}$.  (c) Use (a) and (b) to establish that ${\mathbb Q}$ is the Pontryagin dual of the solenoid group.

Comment: @TerryTao Thank you so much Professor!!!!! These steps explain why the solenoid is the Pontryagin dual of $\mathbb{Q}$ very clearly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No originality here, but I would tell the story as follows. Consider the subgroup $(\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{R})/\mathbb{Z}$ of $(\mathbb{Z}_p\times\mathbb{R})/\mathbb{Z}$. It is dense, because $\mathbb{Z}$ is dense in $\mathbb{Z}_p$. It is also connected, because it is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$ (with a coarser topology than the standard one). Therefore, in the group $(\mathbb{Z}_p\times\mathbb{R})/\mathbb{Z}$, the connected component of the identity is dense, whence it equals $(\mathbb{Z}_p\times\mathbb{R})/\mathbb{Z}$.

The same proof works for $(\widehat{\mathbb{Z}}\times\mathbb{R})/\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: This is nice! However as topological groups, the induced topology of your real line is actually finer than the usual topology of $\mathbb{R}$. For example $p^n$ actually converge in the induced topology

Comment: @YuanYang The induced topology of my real line is actually coarser than the usual topology (there are fewer open sets, hence more convergent sequences). So my real line is still connected (in the coarser topology).

Comment: @YuanYang  perhaps look instead at the composition $\mathbf R \to \mathbf Z \times \mathbf R \to (\mathbf Z \times \mathbf R)/\mathbf Z$, where $\mathbf R$ has its usual topology and we use product and quotient topologies in the second and third groups.  Each map is continuous and the overall map is surjective, so the third space is connected and we don't have to think about unusual topologies on $\mathbf R$.

Comment: @KConrad Well said. Actually the unusual topology on $\mathbb{R}$ is not so bad: the open sets are the usual open sets with periodicity by some $p$-power.

Answer (score 2):

Assume that $(\Bbb{Z}_p\times\mathbb{R})/\Bbb{Z} = U\cup V$ with $U,V$ open non-empty disjoint.

$U$ contains the image of some $(a,b)$ in $\Bbb{Z}_p\times\mathbb{R}$ so it contains the image of an open $(a+p^k\Bbb{Z}_p,b+(-\epsilon,\epsilon))$ and thus it contains the image of the whole of $(a+p^k\Bbb{Z}_p,\Bbb{R})$.

Given an another $(c,d)\in (\Bbb{Z}_p\times\mathbb{R})/\Bbb{Z}$ there is an integer such that $(c+n,d+n)\in U$. So $V$ is in fact empty.

It works the same way for $(\widehat{\mathbb{Z}}\times\mathbb{R})/\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: I think the connected component of $(a,b)$ in $\mathbb{Z}_p \times \mathbb{R}$ is just $a \times \mathbb{R}$. $\mathbb{Z}_p$ is totally disconnected so the connected component of any its element is only itself.

Comment: Ahh thanks for your answer so much!! To my knowledge that’s right

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Connected components are always closed.

Comment: I am so confused… I should prove that the only closed subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}_p\times\mathbb{R}$ containing$ \mathbb{Z}$diagonally is the whole group. How can I prove that?

Comment: add "as well as $0 \times {\mathbb R}$" after "containing ${\mathbb Z}$ diagonally" and you'll be almost done.

Comment: @TerryTao Why should it contain $0\times｛\mathbb R}$? Hhhh I mean, this might be a tiny fact but it still need a proof

Comment: @TerryTao Sorry I just want to ask another crazy question: Is the inherit topology on $0 \times {\mathbb R}$ the same topology on the real line?

Comment: @YuanYang Write $K(G)$ for the connected components of a topological group $G$. The space $K(G)$ is totally disconnected and again a topological group. For $G = \Bbb Z_p \times_{\Bbb Z} \Bbb R$ your goal is to show $K(G) = 1$. So consider the composite $\Bbb Z_p \times \Bbb R \to K(G)$; this is surjective, so it suffices to show its kernel is the whole of $\Bbb Z_p \times \Bbb R$. The kernel contains $0 \times \Bbb R$ because the image of a connected set is connected, and you've seen already it contains the diagonal $\Bbb Z$. So this kernel is closed and contains $\Bbb Z \times \Bbb R$...